# SET the value of SET from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Noob programmer here:

I have a function that sets variables using the SET command. I'm trying to loop through all the records in a table and run the function but I can't figure out how to make it work. Not sure how to get the query to pull in the columns of the current record its looking at or how I should go about looping, or how to SET the results. Tried CROSS APPLY but I couldn't get that to work.

```
if exists(Select Lat, Long From DDD WHERE Ad1 is not Null)
begin
    DECLARE @address nvarchar (100);
    set @address = (Select Ad1 from DDD where ID = id);

    DECLARE @state nvarchar (100);
    SET @state = 'FL';

    DECLARE @zip nvarchar (100);
    SET @zip = (Select AD2 from DDD where ID = id);

    DECLARE @city nvarchar (100);
    SET @city = 'Miami';

    DECLARE @nation nvarchar (2);
    SET @nation = 'us';

    DECLARE @g geography;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.050'
    SET @g = dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip, @address);

    SELECT @g.Long;
    SELECT @g.Lat;
    Update DDD Set Lat = @g.Lat
    Update DDD Set long = @g.Lat
END

[dbo].[DDD](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Day] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CaseNum] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FolioNum] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Ad1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AD2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LD] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[FJ] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[AV] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PMB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[BB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LSSQ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LSQ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[status] [bit] NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[WF] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[Lat] [float] NULL,
[long] [float] NULL,
```

Comment: Show us the schema of DDD. Your update should include a PK (your current example updates the entire table)

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do with the function?

Comment: The function is a geocoder. I provide it with the values and it pulls in the Lat and long from online. That part works I just cant get it to pull in the SET var because I cant SET them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select @address =  Ad1 from DDD where ID = id;
```

Addendum:

I am assuming that the function Geocode returns a table(a single record with Lat and Long fields). You can use CTE to update each row of DDD table as explained below.

Initial Sample Data in DDD:

```
| id | lat | long | Ad |
------------------------     
| 1  | NULL| NULL | A  |
| 2  | NULL| NULL | B  |
| 3  | NULL| NULL | A  |
| 4  | NULL| NULL | C  |
```

Let underlying table from which Geocode function fetched Lat and Long values has data:

```
| Ad | Lat | Long |
-------------------
|  A | 12  | 45   |
|  B | 13  | 55   |
```

Let Geocode function definition is as below:

```
create function Geocode(@add varchar)
returns table
as
return (SELECT * from latlongtable where [add] = @add)
```

Using below query the lat long information in DDD table can be updated:

```
with cte_d(id1,Ad)
as
(
  select ID as id1, Ad from ddd
)
update d 
set d.lat = (select lat from Geo(d.Ad)), long = (select long from Geo(d.Ad)) 
from ddd d 
where d.id = id
```

After above query is run, DDD table looks like this:

```
| id | lat | long | Ad |
------------------------     
| 1  | 12  | 45   | A  |
| 2  | 13  | 55   | B  |
| 3  | 12  | 45   | A  |
| 4  | NULL| NULL | C  |
```

Customize the above CTE query as per your need and let me know if you were able to make it work.

Comment: thats what I currently have and I know it doesn't work. I get the following. (I wish it was that easy) Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13

Comment: Is ID a primary key of DDD table? if not then this won't work.

Comment: Try to see what the query returns when  `id` is replaced with constant: `Select Ad1 from DDD where ID = 12`. Does it return multiple records?

Comment: Sorry, I checked and I failed at copy and paste. it did work. Your great. Any ideas on how I get this to loop and do the other records in the table ?

Comment: Glad it helped, where are you getting `id` parameter from? Try giving some more details in the question.

Comment: id parameter comes from the table itself. It auto generates when a record is created.

Comment: id parameter comes from the table itself. It auto generates when a record is created. its unique and the way i have it setup in my sql DB is that the table DDD is dropped and recreated, the data imported from  a txt  file and placed into the correct location. any dups are removed  and any null values replaced with '0'. the function then runs (or that what im trying to do) and gets the geo locations of each row based on the address (Ad1) in that row

Comment: See the Addendum above

Comment: I have something that is sort of working over here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559484/run-ms-sql-function-against-each-row-in-table) just not sure as to why its only coding based off the very last record.