# Run SQL Server function against each row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a function that which iterates "for each row" in the table. When it is run it should look at each row, pull in the related SET values for that row and run the function which in turns returns a result and updates the correct row with the correct value. What is happening is that it is running and returning the value for the very last row and updating all the row with that value. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
     RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
     ,*
INTO #Geo
FROM DDDG

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #Geo)

DECLARE @Iter INT
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #Geo)

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM #Geo
     WHERE RowNum = @Iter

    DECLARE @address nvarchar (100);
    Select @address =  Ad1 from DDDG where id = @Iter;

    DECLARE @state nvarchar (100);
    SET @state = 'FL';

    DECLARE @zip nvarchar (100);
    SET @zip = '33142';

    DECLARE @city nvarchar (100);
    SET @city = 'Miami';

    DECLARE @nation nvarchar (2);
    SET @nation = 'us';

    DECLARE @g geography;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.050'
    SET @g = dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip, @address);

    Update DDDG 
    Set Lat = @g.Lat 
    where id = @Iter;

    Update DDDG 
    Set long = @g.Long 
    where id = @Iter;

     SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END

DROP TABLE #Geo
```

Update .....

thanks all... I almost got it working.. After a hell of a lot of trial and error I figured out that I needed to change the following

```
Update DDDG Set Lat = @g.Lat where id = id;
Update DDDG Set long = @g.Long where id = id;
```

I only have one problem now. When I delete rows the RowNum and the @Iter no longer match up. is there a way of fixing this problem other than recreating the table every time?

Comment: You should rework the logic to eliminate the loop...SQL is a set based language and performs very poorly like this.  It handles far better when you loose the linear line of thought, one script to update all rows, no loop.

Comment: Are you sure that the Geocode function isn't just returning the same Lattitude and Longitude for every address?

Comment: I am sure (Dr. Wily question)and as for a better way I have been at this for only 6 months or so.. if you can show me a better way.... im all for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE_DDD(ID,Ad1)
AS
(
  SELECT ID, Ad1 FROM DDD
)
UPDATE d 
SET d.lat = dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip,Ad1).lat, long = dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip,Ad1).long 
FROM DDD d 
WHERE d.id = ID
```

Modified Query after getting downvotes from peers for the above one:

```
WITH CTE_DDD AS
(
  SELECT * FROM DDD
)
UPDATE CTE_DDD SET lat = (SELECT lat from dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip,Ad)), long = (SELECT long from    dbo.Geocode(@nation, @state, @city, @zip,Ad))
```

I would agree that CROSS APPLY is a better solution as it would call the function once per row.

Comment: OMG, your the greatest. This is the greatest bit of code that I have ever seen in my whole life.. I would give you 5 stars of I could... this brings a weeks long search to an end.... Im new to all of this, any sites you recommend to a noob, or books?

Comment: Thanks and glad it helped! W3Schools website is good to learn basic stuffs from; and of-course you would get nice articles on the internet written by SQL Gurus. Start with Joins, Select, Insert, Delete, Update, grouping, CTE, row_number()...I have discovered lately that being active on forums like this one, is good way to learn, so I would recommend it to you too.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this even work?, you are not providing a table alias for `Ad1`, so it should give an error. And why would you need to do a `JOIN` with itself, it's much much more simple to just update the table

Comment: @Lamak, he is not joining the table to itself (unless the answer was edited). He is defining a CTE which is not used at all. And the `WHERE d.id = ID` is totally redundant...

Comment: @ypercube You are right, of course. The `id = ID` threw me off and I assumed it was a `JOIN`

Comment: @DipenduPaul So, after reading your edit, why do you need a CTE, if the CTE has actually the same exact data as the table?

Comment: @ypercube, you are right, my bad, I tried CTE for row-wise update. But I got to know that even an update directly on the table would have given the same results as @Lamak's first solution. I will keep the solution here, for others to know how not misuse CTE. Thanks to you. A clarification from you: what is return type of Geocode function, is it a table? update statement does not accept this way of accessing lat field: `dbo.GeoCode('us','FL','Miami','33142',Ad1).Lat`

Answer (score 9):

I may be missing something, but why do you need a loop at all?:

```
UPDATE DDDG
SET Lat     = dbo.GeoCode('us','FL','Miami','33142',Ad1).Lat,
    Long    = dbo.GeoCode('us','FL','Miami','33142',Ad1).Long;
```

It is also possible to improve the query further by reducing the number of calls to `dbo.GeoCode` to just one per row:

```
UPDATE t
SET Lat     = g.GC.Lat,
    Long    = g.GC.Long
FROM DDDG AS t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT dbo.GeoCode('us','FL','Miami','33142',Ad1) AS GC
) AS g;
```

Comment: I tried that but when run that way it updates all the records with the last address in the table

Comment: @user3266908 well, you aren't specifying a way to know which is the *last*  address for a row

Comment: this query would update the whole table as WHERE condition is missing, and only the last Ad1's lat and long would be updated in all the records.

Comment: @DipenduPaul there isn't a `WHERE` condition in the question, and op is looping through the whole table

Comment: user3266908 has used `where id = @Iter` in the query.

Comment: @DipenduPaul That's because he is doing a loop. He is using that to go through every single one of the ids of the table. I presented a set based solution, hence the reason why I'm not using a `WHERE`

Comment: thanks all... I almost got it working.. After a hell of a lot of trial and error I figured out that I needed to change the follow

Comment: @Lamak, just curious, what is the return type of Geocode. I have assumed it to be Table, am I right?