# Understanding SQL Language

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me understand this query better? I want to remove all special characters from my string but I don't understand how to apply it to my own query. I found this query on Stackoverflow and it seems to work for some people. I'm assuming @str is my string name but I don't know what @expres stands for. And do I need a select/from statement?

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
      SET @str = '(remove) ~special~ *characters. from string in sql!'
      WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
          SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
```

Comment: @ is a variable declaration in SQL, after this you can just do SELECT @str

Comment: @LuisBecerril Can you show me an example of how you would do it? I don't understand what you mean by variable declaration.

Comment: just add "SELECT @str" after the previous query and execute it all at once

Comment: This is what I did and it's still giving me special characters.



`use SBLReporting
select  name
from bbnet.customerrelationship

DECLARE @ str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @ expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
SET @ str = '(remove) ~special~ *characters. from string in sql!'
WHILE PATINDEX( @ expres, @ str ) > 0
SET @ str = Replace(REPLACE( @ str, SUBSTRING( @ str, PATINDEX( @ expres, @ str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')`

Answer (score 1):

From the code above there are a couple of things you need to understand first

- `@` in `sql` is a form of variable declaration, meaning your assigning a value to that name
- `@express` in this case is the list of characters you want to remove from the string. so anything inside the `[]` will be searched for in the next section of the code
- `PATINDEX` is a function that will search through your `@string` to see if theres any matches with what you put in `@express`. IF there is, it will return the index of the start of the match.
- putting this condition inside the `WHILE` means that it will loop through the `@string` until there is no match, meaning all matches have been removed
- The final `SET` line is where the removal happens. This is accomplished using `REPLACE`.
- `REPLACE` takes 3 arguments; the string you are searching through, in this case `@string`, the pattern you are trying to replace, in this case `@expres` and finally what you will replace it with, in this case `' '` and `'-'`
- The `SUBSTRING` inside the `REPLACE` is trying to find the first thing it wants to replace. to do this it need to find where the pattern starts, therefor it uses `PATINDEX` to find where the index of it is

I hope that was clear enough. you can find the documentation for [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) here

Comment: I understand a fair amount of what you are describing. But I still don't know how to apply it to my own query.

Comment: Its great to know you understood what I was trying to explain!. I think the answer provided by @Luis is a great example of how to implement the code. check it out below and see if that works or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze the SQL you will see that you are stripping characters from the @str variable. Therefore you need to set it to the value you want the characters to be stripped from.

```
use SBLReporting 
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400) 
SELECT @str = name from bbnet.customerrelationship --here you set the @str variable to your desired value
DECLARE @expres VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0 SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @ expres, @ str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
SELECT @str -- this will be your stripped value
```

Comment: @LuisBercerril. This is a very helpful response. However, now that I did that and I executed my query. I only came up with 1 row. Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: Yes, this function only strips one string and is being applied only to the first result of your select. You should isolate this function into a SQL function and call it against all the rows in your desired table. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559484/run-sql-server-function-against-each-row-in-table

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the string to be stripped of its special characters as @str.

The snippet `DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)` simply says that @str is a variable of type varchar that can contain up to 400 characters.

Lets suppose your string is "Special Characters Are Things Like $#@%" your code would be:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
      SET @str = 'Special Characters Are Things Like $#@%'
      WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
      SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
```

Finally execute `SELECT @str` and you should see "Special Characters Are Things Like " as your output.

Comment: With my reply to Luis Becerril. What am I doing wrong to not remove special characters?

`use SBLReporting
select  name
from bbnet.customerrelationship

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
SET @str = '(remove) ~special~ *characters. from string in sql!'
WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')`